# Determine if a record was created or updated in a formula (process builder)?

Tags: workflow, formula, process-builder

Similar to the [trigger context variable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm) `Trigger.isInsert`, is there a way to determine if a record was created (as opposed to edited), in a criteria in Process Builder?

I tried using `ISCHANGED(CreatedDate)`, but it appears that the process is fired after database insertion, so this doesn't do the job...

I can probably use something like (pseudocode) `CreatedDate >= NOW() - 10s`, but this seems rather inelegant, and could fail in edge cases (e.g. someone edits immediately after creation, or on record creation the system lags and the process doesn't fire in the expected window of time).

Is there a simple solution to this that I'm overlooking?

Comment: I've not used it but I thought you could use isNew(). Have you seen this? https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DfRIAA0

Comment: Yes `ISNEW function` should work

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks much gentlemen. Post that as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding my comment as an answer (I'll add more detail shortly) :
I've not used it but I thought you could use isNew(). Have you seen this? https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DfRIAA0